# Separate the innerHTML of multiple tags

Tags: javascript

Having a code like this:

```
<div id="myid">
    <div class="test">
        <h3 class="h3_class">My Title</h3>
        <p class="class_1_p">Text 1</p>
        <p class="Sans-19px">
            test text 3
        </p>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="test_light">
    <blockquote class="test_text_final">
        An example final text
    </blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

It is possible to take the inner HTML using the following code:

```
document.querySelector('div#myid').innerText
```

Is there any way to separate which let's say a comma the text from every tag?

Expected output:

```
My Title,Text 1,test text 3,An example final text
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question/the last line? It isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: Can you rephrase your questions? What do you want to seperate? What should be seperated to what? Especially the `a comma the text from every tag?`, can't understand you at all.

Edit: Simon was 13 secs quicker. :(

Comment: Are you asking how to get an array of all elements matching "div#myid" that also have a comma in the innerText?

Comment: @SimonK I added an expected example output. Does it help? Thank for your comments.

Comment: Yeah, just crawl it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a VanillaJS one line solution:

```js
var text = document.querySelector('div#myid').innerText;

console.log(text.split('\n').filter(x => x).join(', '));
```

```html
<div id="myid">
    <div class="test">
        <h3 class="h3_class">My Title</h3>
        <p class="class_1_p">Text 1</p>
        <p class="Sans-19px">
            test text 3
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="test_light">
        <blockquote class="test_text_final">
            An example final text
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This assumes that each node is on a newline, which is generally not a safe assumption for HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly with `innerText`. What you would have to do is iterate through the HTML recursively until you got to the last leaf that only has text, and then return each of those.

```js
const root = document.querySelector('#myid');

const getTexts = (el, chunks = []) => {
  if (el.nodeType === document.TEXT_NODE) {
    return chunks.concat(el.data);
  } else if (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(el.childNodes, (result, child) => getTexts(child, result), chunks);
  }
  
  return chunks;
}

console.log(getTexts(root));
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="myid">
      <div class="test">
          <h3 class="h3_class">My Title</h3>
          <p class="class_1_p">Text 1</p>
          <p class="Sans-19px">
              test text 3
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test_light">
      <blockquote class="test_text_final">
          An example final text
      </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you'll notice, this function also includes newlines (`\n`) and spaces, which you can filter out if you want.

The function basically goes through each node. If it is a `TextNode`, it reads the text and adds it to the chunk. If it's not, but has children, it'll then recurse through each of the children. If it's neither, it just returns the existing chunks.

```js
const root = document.querySelector('#root');

const getTexts = (el, chunks = []) => {
  if (el.nodeType === document.TEXT_NODE) {
    return chunks.concat(el.data);
  } else if (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(el.childNodes, (result, child) => getTexts(child, result), chunks);
  }
  
  return chunks;
}

console.log(
  getTexts(root).map(s => s.trim()).filter(Boolean)
);
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div id="myid">
      <div class="test">
          <h3 class="h3_class">My Title</h3>
          <p class="class_1_p">Text 1</p>
          <p class="Sans-19px">
              test text 3
          </p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test_light">
      <blockquote class="test_text_final">
          An example final text
      </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This loops through all elements in #myid and if the text input is more than 0, it adds to result and then gives you an alert, is this what you want?

```js
var result = "";

$("#myid *").each(function(index) {
  if($(this).text().length > 0) {
      result += $(this).text().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") + ",";
  }
});
alert(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myid">
    <div class="test">
        <h3 class="h3_class">My Title</h3>
        <p class="class_1_p">Text 1</p>
        <p class="Sans-19px">
            test text 3
        </p>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="test_light">
    <blockquote class="test_text_final">
        An example final text
    </blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: Consider using Boris's solution instead.

Comment: This one is actually safer than Boris' solution since it doesn't rely on whitespace for splitting.

Answer (score -1):

This one grabs everything inside given selector.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("myid").innerText.replace(/\s{2,}/g,', '));
```

```html
<div id="myid">
    <div class="test">
        <h3 class="h3_class">My Title</h3>
        <p class="class_1_p">Text 1</p>
        <p class="Sans-19px">
            test text 3
        </p>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="test_light">
    <blockquote class="test_text_final">
        An example final text
    </blockquote>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Making assumptions about the whitespace in HTML is generally not safe.

Comment: can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Your solution works by splitting on spaces and replacing those with commas. That isn't really an array, but also it wouldn't work if there were those spaces. For example, if your HTML was this: `<div><p>A</p><p>B</p><p>C</p></div>`, you would just get `ABC` without them being separated.